# Google Sheets Formula Issue "=IF(A1,A1,IF(B1="","",NOW()))"

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

We are facing some issues with google sheets, write a formula =IF(A1,A1,IF(B1="","",NOW())) when dore did his work on time Timestamp come same but when he come next day or 2, 3 days open the sheet Timestamp was a change on that time when he was open, The formula was working fine. But What is happening is that the timestamp is recalculating every time the sheet is re-opened. Curiously, this recalculation is only affecting the latest 5 or so rows.
I'm trying multiple formula

1. =IF(B6,B6,IF(C6="","",$A$1))
2. =IF(T9,T9,IF(V9<>"",$A$1,""))
3. =IF(H6,H6,IF(I6<>"",NOW(),""))

[image]

Comment: timestamp is not possible to get without script

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130253/186471

Answer (score 0):

NOW() is not a static value. It is dynamic and it recalculates.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en

Google sheet does not recalculate all the time because it would be resource heavy if it did.

It probably seemed 'fine' because the recalculation didn't occur until later when you made other changes or when you closed and reopened it. This is not a correct way to implement timestamp.

My suggestion is to implement an app script to actually enter in the static value. There are many resources online and they are easy to implement. Here's the first one that comes up when I run a search:

http://blog.danwin.com/how-to-automatically-timestamp-a-new-row-in-google-sheets-using-apps-script/